# How to update a vector in method

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand vectors. My goal is to update a vector in method:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(vector<int>& array){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        array.push_back(i);
    }
}

int main(){
    // some integer value
    vector<int> array(10);

    test(array);

    for(int i=0;i<array.size();++i)
        cout<<array.at(i)<<endl;

    cout<<"array size:"<<array.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
array size:20
```

I haven't figure out why 10 zeros add vector at first?

Comment: Look at a reference. That's what the constructor does, then you push more on the back.

Comment: [2nd constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> array(10);
```

This creates 10 open slots in the array. In your `test1` method `push_back` will write to the *end* of those 10 slots.

You need to either use `[i]` or `at(i)` for index selection, or remove the size:

```
std::vector<int> array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> array(10);
```

This declares a `vector<int>` with 10 elements, all of them have value `0`, then later you `push_back` other values. According what you mean, you should use an empty vector:

```
vector<int> array;
```

then add the elements later like you did.

Answer (score 0):

Because `vector<int> array(10);` predefines first 10 elements to 0's. Use:

```
vector<int> array;
array.reserve(10);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you wanted you should substitute push_back for for example the subscript operator

```
void test( vector<int> &array )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i < array.size() ; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
}

Another way is to use standard algorithm std::iota

void test( vector<int> &array )
{
    std::iota( array.begin(), array.end(), 0 );
}
```

Or if your compiler supports std::initializer_list you could define your array in main the following way without calling function test

```
std::vector<int> array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```